# Continuity and uniform continuity of $|x|$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a$ be a real number. Use the definition of continuity via sequences to prove that the function $f(x)= |x|$ is continuous at $x=a$. Is this function uniformly continuous on $[-1,1]$? Is it over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: What is the difference between uniformly continuous and normally continuous?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [MSE quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a_n\to a$. Does it follow that $|a_n|\to a$? Use that $$||a_n|-|a||\leq |a_n-a|$$

Yet again, use that for any $x,y\in\Bbb R$, we have $$||x|-|y||<|x-y|$$

If I give you $\epsilon >0$, can you pick a $\delta >0$ that depends *only* on $\epsilon$ such that $|x-y|<\delta\implies ||x|-|y||<\epsilon$?

Comment: would that just be δ<ϵ in this case?

Comment: Yes. Or $\delta =\epsilon$.